# Why does id value change when referring fixtures in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I have the following fixtures.

```
users.yml

first_user:
  name: User1
  password_hash: <%= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret('password', '$2a$10$xKPXy2QabH6ThBjo7gNB8O') %>
  password_salt: $2a$10$xKPXy2QabH6ThBjo7gNB8O
  role: 1

stores.yml
one:
  name: MyFirstString
  user_id: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:first_user) %>
```

However, when I load `Store.first.user_id` I get the value as `979462526` while `User.first.id` is `980190962`. I think these values should not be different. Please correct my understanding or point out error in my code if any. The model structure is: a user has many stores.

Comment: Clearly that is equal to 979462526.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:first_user)` has nothing to do with `first_user` fixture itself.
See [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L576).

According to comment it just generates identifier for a given label. In you case it's `:first_user`.

So you can just open `rails console` and do it by hands

```
Zlib.crc32('first_user') % (2 ** 30 - 1) 
# => 979462526
```

And you will get just the same number.
So it has nothing to do with any particular fixture (since I don't have any fixtures).

**UPDATE**

Maybe you should try to use associations instead of linking ids directly.

```
# users.yml
first_user:
  name: User1
  ...

# stores.yml
one:
  name: MyFirstString
  user: first_user
```

This way I hope it should work like expected.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the explanation. The idea was to refer to the user object's id value in stores.yml. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I don't usually use fixtures, give me some time to check it.

Comment: Sure. If you can add that, it will be really helpful.

Comment: did read this [guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)? Section **Label references for associations (belongs_to, has_one, has_many)**. I will update my answer, not sure if it works but you can try it